# How to find a relationship between the depresion angle when an observer is descending over an incline?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> An astronomer is located atop of a cliff to watch a star from his
> telescope on the evening. The position of the astronomer is on point
> $A$ (Assume this is indicated in the drawing). The cliff has an
> incline with respect of the surface where there's a lake labeled
> $\theta$. From this position he sees a safety buoy with a bell and
> light beacon located on point $P$ on the lake with a depression angle
> $\alpha$. Minutes later the astronomer descends down the cliff to the
> midpoint and sees the safety buoy again with a depression angle
> $\beta$.
>
> Using this information find:
> $$B=\frac{\cot\theta+\cot\beta}{\cot\alpha}$$

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&5\\
2.&3\\
3.&2\\
4.&1\\
\end{array}$

What I've attempted so far was to use a relationship to relate the height of the cliff to which I named $c$ as:

$h=c \sin \theta$

Since the mentions that the depression angle when he's atop the clif is $\alpha$ then this would meant:

$c\sin\theta\cot\alpha=d$

where $d$ is the distance between the safety buoy and the astronomer when he's atop the cliff which comes from

$c\sin\theta=h$

But other than that I can't seem to find any other relationship here. Can someone help me here?.

Does it exist some relationship which I'm overlooking?.

Comment: $\cot \theta = \frac{NR}{MN}$ ,  $\cot \beta = \frac{PN}{MN}$,  add

Answer (score 1):

The general approach I took to this question was, let me find $\cot \alpha,$ $\cot \beta,$ and $\cot \theta$ somewhere in the figure and see if I can get an equation with $\cot \alpha$ (possibly multiplied by something) on one side and the sum of $\cot \beta$ and $\cot \theta$ (possibly multiplied by something) on the other, and hope that I can cancel enough of the "something else" on each side so that I can divide both sides by $\cot\alpha$ and be left with just a single constant factor.

Marking up the figure as shown below may help.
Let $R$ be found by dropping a perpendicular from $A$ onto the extended line $PQ$, let $M$ be the midpoint of $AQ,$ and let $N$ be the midpoint of $QR.$

[image]

You have already determined that $h = AR = AP \sin \alpha.$
More directly relevant to the question, you have also determined that
$PR = h \cot \alpha.$

Note that $\triangle MNQ$ is similar to $\triangle ARQ$ with
$MN = \frac h2$ and that $\angle ARQ,$ $\angle MNQ,$ and $\angle MNR$
are all right angles.
Since $NQ=NR$ you can find that $\triangle MNQ \cong \triangle MNR$.

See what additional relationships the triangles in the figure give you that use the ratios
$\cot \beta$ and $\cot \theta.$
In particular you can look at $PN/MN$ and $NR/MN.$

Comment: You're always right on point. But **how exactly** do I come to the conclusion that $\triangle MQR$ is isosceles?. In my original drawing from my sketchbook (not featured) I drawn the $\angle \beta$ exactly in the same way as it is shown $\alpha$ in other words a line i.e $MH \parallel PR$. But using the identity which mentions that the alternate interior angles on a diagonal that crosses parallel lines are equal, I ended up with the same drawing as yours. However I'm still tangled with equations?.

Comment: Can you help me with an additional hint on where should I look for to get a quick relation to get the answer?. Should I go with sines law?.

Comment: Well after a day of trying I found to be $2$ the answer as both cotangents cancel. Did you arrived to the same answer?. It has to be noted that this problem was made in such a way that although we do not know specifically the values of the angles it can be simplified.

Comment: I got the same result as you. Very clever question, isn't it. Makes one wonder how someone came up with it.

Answer (score 0):

We start by defining some points.

Let $X$ be the intersection between the horizontal line passing through $A$ and the vertical line passing through $P$, and let $Y$ be the intersection between the horizontal line passing through the midpoint of the cliff surface and the vertical line passing through $P$.

Furthermore let $Z$ be the point of intersection between the cliff surface and the lake, and $W$ the point of intersection between the vertical line through $A$ and the horizontal line through $P$.

Let $h$ be the height of the cliff, $x$ the distance between $Z$ and $W$, $w_\alpha$ the distance between $X$ and $A$, and $w_\beta$ the distance between $Y$ and the midpoint of the cliff surface.

Then we have $\tan \alpha = \frac{h}{w_\alpha},$ $\tan \beta = \frac{h}{2w_\beta},$ and $\tan \theta = \frac{h}{x}$. Substituting these into the expression for $B$ and using the fact that $w_\alpha - w_\beta = \frac{x}{2}$ should get you the result.

Comment: Hi I found the answer to be $2$ did you get the same answer?. In the end it seemed that the expressions both cancel. So it seems that this problem was made in such a way that you can find the answer without knowing specifically the values of the angles either on the top, or the incline or the midpoint.

Comment: Yes, I got $B = 2$ as well.